# On Ubuntu 20.04 (Lenovo Thinkpad), display scale of 100% is tiny, 200% is still small

Tags: display, 20.04, lenovo, display-resolution, thinkpad

Just got a Lenovo Thinkpad, installed Ubuntu 20.04, and below are the screenshots of my full screen when checking the display scale options for

- 100% scale: as you may see, the font/symbols are insanely tiny
  [image]
- 200% scale: still pretty small, hence I had to roll with 300% (which is on a larger side, but there's no option for fractional scaling at 250%, it's only available between 100 and 200)
  [image]

Does anyone know why that is happening? Why is scale of 100% looking so tiny as opposed to being a reasonable option as usual? Is it likely to be a Lenovo issue rather than Ubuntu 20.04? I'd used Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04 on Dell before (not 20.04 though), and it was never an issue. Or maybe it's due to resolution?

Comment: fractional scaling have you tried which is 1.25 1.5 1.75 etc?

Comment: Fractional scaling works only between 100 and 200, which are both too small. Unfortunately it doesn't extend beyond 200 (it least judging by what I see from GUI), because 250 or so would've been perfect

Comment: in your screenshot I observed that you have not turned on fractional scaling.. 0r am I wronG??

Comment: If I turn it on, it will just give me the 100-125-150-175-200 options, none of which are large enough

Comment: 0k.. you can manually adjust the scale.. can you paste the output 0f `cat $HOME/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: Apologies for delay in response:  <monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x07c8</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>3840</width>
          <height>2160</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does not know the size of your screen and thus does not know about its pixel density.

For example on a 15" screen 100% might be tiny, but on a 32" screen with the same resolution 100% would fit just fine. That is why you can change the scaling to fit your screen size manually.

Your Lenovo laptop has a higher pixel density than your Dell Laptop.

Comment: Got it, thank you. With that said, does there happen to be an option for fractional scaling for ranges above 200? E.g. I have options 100, 200, 300, 400; and then for fractional I have everything in-between 100 & 200, but nothing above 200 (e.g. 250 would've probably been perfect)

Comment: I think this would definitely be a good question to ask here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***Workaround***

run the below command when fractional scale is not enabled.

[image]

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState
```

Example:

```
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState
(uint32 7, [(('eDP-1-1', 'SDC', '0x4141', '0x00000000'), [('1366x768@59.998008728027344', 1366, 768, 59.998008728027344, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {'is-preferred': <true>}), ('1360x768@59.798992156982422', 1360, 768, 59.798992156982422, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {}), ('1360x768@59.960025787353516', 1360, 768, 59.960025787353516, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {'is-current': <true>}), ('1280x720@120.00162506103516', 1280, 720, 120.00162506103516, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@119.98211669921875', 1280, 720, 119.98211669921875, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@59.855125427246094', 1280, 720, 59.855125427246094, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@59.744712829589844', 1280, 720, 59.744712829589844, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {}), ('1024x768@120.07466888427734', 1024, 768, 120.07466888427734, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('1024x768@60.003841400146484', 1024, 768, 60.003841400146484, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x720@120', 960, 720, 120.0, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('928x696@120.101318359375', 928, 696, 120.101318359375, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('896x672@120.02888488769531', 896, 672, 120.02888488769531, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('1024x576@119.90670776367188', 1024, 576, 119.90670776367188, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('1024x576@119.91866302490234', 1024, 576, 119.91866302490234, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('1024x576@59.899215698242188', 1024, 576, 59.899215698242188, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('1024x576@59.819515228271484', 1024, 576, 59.819515228271484, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x600@119.865478515625', 960, 600, 119.865478515625, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x600@119.99750518798828', 960, 600, 119.99750518798828, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x540@119.92568969726562', 960, 540, 119.92568969726562, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x540@119.97574615478516', 960, 540, 119.97574615478516, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x540@59.6290283203125', 960, 540, 59.6290283203125, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('960x540@59.818218231201172', 960, 540, 59.818218231201172, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('800x600@120', 800, 600, 120.0, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('800x600@60.316539764404297', 800, 600, 60.316539764404297, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('800x600@56.25', 800, 600, 56.25, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('840x525@120.01870727539062', 840, 525, 120.01870727539062, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('840x525@119.76650238037109', 840, 525, 119.76650238037109, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('864x486@59.91534423828125', 864, 486, 59.91534423828125, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('864x486@59.5703125', 864, 486, 59.5703125, 1.0, [1.0], {}), ('800x512@120.33700561523438', 800, 512, 120.33700561523438, 1.0, [1.0], {})], {'is-builtin': <true>, 'display-name': <'Built-in display'>})], [(0, 0, 1.0, uint32 0, true, [('eDP-1-1', 'SDC', '0x4141', '0x00000000')], @a{sv} {})], {'renderer': <'xrandr'>, 'layout-mode': <uint32 2>, 'global-scale-required': <true>, 'legacy-ui-scaling-factor': <1>, 'max-screen-size': <(16384, 16384)>})
$
```

from the above result, note that at the start of the output "(unit32 7" the value 7 varies and it is very important. Note that value in your case.

Next read the common pattern with many different values.. like this

```
'1366x768@59.998008728027344', 1366, 768, 59.998008728027344, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0]
```

`1366x768@59.998008728027344`: **mode ID**
`1366`: **width in physical pixels**
`768`: **height in physical pixels**
`59.998008728027344`: **refresh rate**
`1.0`: **scale preferred as per calculations**
`[1.0, 2.0]`: **scales supported by the above mode** (`1366x768@59.998008728027344`)

This means that out of the available modes..( there are plenty of modes as per the output ) If you choose `1366x768@59.998008728027344` this mode.. you have only two scales available `[1.0, 2.0]`

Now enable the fractional scale and run the command again..

```
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState
(uint32 7, [(('eDP-1-1', 'SDC', '0x4141', '0x00000000'), [('1366x768@59.998008728027344', 1366, 768, 59.998008728027344, 1.0, [1.0, 2.0], {'is-preferred': <true>}), ('1360x768@59.798992156982422', 1360, 768, 59.798992156982422, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2307692766189575, 1.4545454978942871, 1.7777777910232544, 2.0], {}), ('1360x768@59.960025787353516', 1360, 768, 59.960025787353516, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2307692766189575, 1.4545454978942871, 1.7777777910232544, 2.0], {'is-current': <true>}), ('1280x720@120.00162506103516', 1280, 720, 120.00162506103516, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5094339847564697, 1.7391303777694702, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@119.98211669921875', 1280, 720, 119.98211669921875, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5094339847564697, 1.7391303777694702, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@59.855125427246094', 1280, 720, 59.855125427246094, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5094339847564697, 1.7391303777694702, 2.0], {}), ('1280x720@59.744712829589844', 1280, 720, 59.744712829589844, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5094339847564697, 1.7391303777694702, 2.0], {}), ('1024x768@120.07466888427734', 1024, 768, 120.07466888427734, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2487804889678955, 1.4970760345458984], {}), ('1024x768@60.003841400146484', 1024, 768, 60.003841400146484, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2487804889678955, 1.4970760345458984], {}), ('960x720@120', 960, 720, 120.0, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('928x696@120.101318359375', 928, 696, 120.101318359375, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2473118305206299], {}), ('896x672@120.02888488769531', 896, 672, 120.02888488769531, 1.0, [1.0, 1.251396656036377], {}), ('1024x576@119.90670776367188', 1024, 576, 119.90670776367188, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2799999713897705, 1.4883720874786377], {}), ('1024x576@119.91866302490234', 1024, 576, 119.91866302490234, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2799999713897705, 1.4883720874786377], {}), ('1024x576@59.899215698242188', 1024, 576, 59.899215698242188, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2799999713897705, 1.4883720874786377], {}), ('1024x576@59.819515228271484', 1024, 576, 59.819515228271484, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2799999713897705, 1.4883720874786377], {}), ('960x600@119.865478515625', 960, 600, 119.865478515625, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('960x600@119.99750518798828', 960, 600, 119.99750518798828, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('960x540@119.92568969726562', 960, 540, 119.92568969726562, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('960x540@119.97574615478516', 960, 540, 119.97574615478516, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('960x540@59.6290283203125', 960, 540, 59.6290283203125, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('960x540@59.818218231201172', 960, 540, 59.818218231201172, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25, 1.5], {}), ('800x600@120', 800, 600, 120.0, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25], {}), ('800x600@60.316539764404297', 800, 600, 60.316539764404297, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25], {}), ('800x600@56.25', 800, 600, 56.25, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25], {}), ('840x525@120.01870727539062', 840, 525, 120.01870727539062, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25], {}), ('840x525@119.76650238037109', 840, 525, 119.76650238037109, 1.0, [1.0, 1.25], {}), ('864x486@59.91534423828125', 864, 486, 59.91534423828125, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2558139562606812], {}), ('864x486@59.5703125', 864, 486, 59.5703125, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2558139562606812], {}), ('800x512@120.33700561523438', 800, 512, 120.33700561523438, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2799999713897705], {})], {'is-builtin': <true>, 'display-name': <'Built-in display'>})], [(0, 0, 1.0, uint32 0, true, [('eDP-1-1', 'SDC', '0x4141', '0x00000000')], @a{sv} {})], {'renderer': <'xrandr'>, 'layout-mode': <uint32 3>, 'supports-changing-layout-mode': <true>, 'x11-fractional-scaling': <true>, 'legacy-ui-scaling-factor': <1>, 'max-screen-size': <(16384, 16384)>})
$
```

This time observe the lines again,

```
'1360x768@59.960025787353516', 1360, 768, 59.960025787353516, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2307692766189575, 1.4545454978942871, 1.7777777910232544, 2.0]
```

Observe that now available scales are changed. this means you can set from the above output 1.23.......... or 1.45.......... or 1.77....... or 2.0

Since my laptop is 1366x768 it has less scales available.. but when I connect it to my 4K TV.. I will have more available scales.. In your case.. your laptop is hi pixelated, you will have the more options for your desired resolution `3840x2168`

So first run the command

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState
```

and note down the values

for example:

1. `7` in Unit32 7 at the start of the output of the above command
2. `1360x768@59.798992156982422` in the preferred mode and which suits the nearly required scale

Example line of my requirement:

```
('1360x768@59.798992156982422', 1360, 768, 59.798992156982422, 1.0, [1.0, 1.2307692766189575, 1.4545454978942871, 1.7777777910232544, 2.0]
```

3. `1.7777777910232544` is the scale which I preferred out of the available for example..
4. `eDP-1-1` this is my Display Change this in your case.

Now to set the scale, in your case you will definitely have 2.25 or 2.50 nearly equivalent values.. edit the below command to suit your values..

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.ApplyMonitorsConfig 7 1 "[(0, 0, 1.7777777910232544, 0, true, [('eDP-1-1', '1360x768@59.798992156982422', [] )] )]" "[]"
```

The explanation of the above command and source is available  [https://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538054/383311)

Successful command example: below gif cant show you accurately but the result is fine in my case..

[image]