# 225/250% scaling options on Ubuntu 20.04? 100 & 200% too small, 300% too large on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: display, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

On Ubuntu 20.04, are there fractional scaling options for **scales over 200% (e.g. 225% or 250%)**? I currently see

- the basic options of 100%, 200%, 300%, 400%,
- fractional scaling options between 100% and 200%

My issue is that the 100-200% displays appear way too small for my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop (for screenshots, please see [On Ubuntu 20.04 (Lenovo Thinkpad), display scale of 100% is tiny, 200% is still small](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248714/on-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-thinkpad-display-scale-of-100-is-tiny-200-is-still?noredirect=1#comment2106865_1248714)), while 300% is a bit on a larger side, hence 225/250% would've been perfect, but I wonder if there's some workaround to get such fractional displays.

Comment: Def need this. These 4k laptops are too tiny for 200% (mine is HP Spectre 19").
Maybe there's some .conf file somewhere where this percentage can manually be typed in